ECR image push from AWS CodeBuild saying region is missing
I am trying to connect my AWS ECR to AWS codebuild through pushes to github. However, every time I push the build is erroring at logging into the ECR. I have gone into the IAM roles for the codebuild to allow greater permissions but no matter what I do I am seeing that the region isn't defined.
Here is my buildspec.yml file
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=****.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/****
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name”:"****","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json




One thing I noticed in your screenshot is that you're using v1 of the amazon-ecr-login, maybe try with v2?

@tzengia still experiencing the same behavior even with the update

Why are you using both GitHub Actions and CodeBuild when they essentially doing the same things. The error you've provided doesn't appear to be from CodeBuild; it seems to be from GitHub Actions. please check codebuild logs to see the proper logs and use try to use only 1 platform.

You've put the CodeBuild (buildspec.yaml) file instead of the Github Actions (.github/workflows/yourWorflowFile.yml) on your question.
Assuming that you have the Github Actions file setup (which it seems to be, based on your screenshot), is just a matter o logging into the ECR before pushing.
Like this:
push:
runs-on: ubunbu-latest

steps:
  - name: Configure AWS Credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

  - name: Login to Amazon ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2

  - name: Push Docker Image
    if: success()
    run: |
      IMAGE_TAG=${{ github.sha }}
      REPOSITORY_URI=${{ secrets.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ secrets.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    env:
      AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

